# Disable collision for certain event sources in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Hi I want to have an event source which allows overlaying(collision with) other event sources without resizing.

But the other event sources should still be using the normal collision detection and resizing?

Did somebody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

First change the function segCollide(seg1, seg2) in fullcalendar to:

```
function segsCollide(seg1, seg2) {
    if(seg1.allowCollision || seg2.allowCollision)
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return seg1.end > seg2.start && seg1.start < seg2.end;
    }
}
```

And sliceSegs() to:

```
function sliceSegs(events, visEventEnds, start, end) {
    var segs = [],
                i, len=events.length, event,
          eventStart, eventEnd,
          segStart, segEnd,
      isStart, isEnd;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        event = events[i];
        allowCollision = event.source.allowCollision;
        eventStart = event.start;
        eventEnd = visEventEnds[i];
        if (eventEnd > start && eventStart < end) {
            if (eventStart < start) {
                segStart = cloneDate(start);
                isStart = false;
            }else{
                segStart = eventStart;
                isStart = true;
            }
            if (eventEnd > end) {
                segEnd = cloneDate(end);
                isEnd = false;
            }else{
                segEnd = eventEnd;
                isEnd = true;
            }


            segs.push({
            event: event,
              start: segStart,
              end: segEnd,
              allowCollision: allowCollision,
              isStart: isStart,
              isEnd: isEnd,
              msLength: segEnd - segStart
            });
        }
    } 
    return segs.sort(segCmp);
}
```